# Kafka is Creating too Many kafka-producer-network-thread due to which there is no Buffer Space to create new Connections

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm trying to Download Emails from Graph API and Once Mails are downloaded I'm Using Kafka Producer to send a Notification To Consumer read those Mails.

Currently I'm using Spring-Kafka Version 2.8.0 and Kafka Version 3.3.1

But after some time Kafka Producer has Created too Many **kafka-producer-network-thread** due to which there is no Buffer Space to create new Connections.

[image]

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:476)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:218)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:162)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:394)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:606)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:339)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:357)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1226)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1162)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1056)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:990)
        at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:76)
        at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
        at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:66)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:775)
```

I've tried Different Properties in order to Reduce the batch Size, Increasing the Buffer Space and other Different Configurations based on one the Ref that I found in StackOverflow(https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/apache-kafka/content/kafka-producer-internals-Sender.html) But none of them Worked as of now

This is my Producer

```
public void send(String topic, String key, KafkaMessageEmailPolling kafkaMessageEmailPolling) {
        try {
            kafkaTemplate = kafkaTemplate();
            kafkaTemplate.send(topic, key, kafkaMessageEmailPolling);
           
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public ProducerFactory<String, Object> producerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<String, Object>(producerConfigs());
    }

    public Map<String, Object> producerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, CustomSerializerEmailPolling.class);
      //Added Changes
        props.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "1");
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG, 10); //16384
        props.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, 3);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.LINGER_MS_CONFIG, 5);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "all");
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BUFFER_MEMORY_CONFIG, 33554432);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_REQUEST_SIZE_CONFIG, 1024);

        return props;
    }

    public KafkaTemplate<String, Object> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<String, Object>(producerFactory());
    }
```

And This is my Consumer

```
    @Autowired
    private WorkItemService workItemService;
    
    public static Consumer<?, ?> createConsumer(String topic) {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, topic);
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, CustomDeserializerEmailPolling.class.getName());
        return new KafkaConsumer<>(properties);
    }
    
    public void consumeMessage(String topic) {
        Consumer<?, ?> consumer = createConsumer(topic);
        List<ConsumerRecord<?, ?>> buffer = new ArrayList<>();
        while (true) {
            //subscribe topic and consume message
            consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(topic));

            ConsumerRecords<?, ?> consumerRecords =
                    consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(600000));
            for (ConsumerRecord<?, ?> record : consumerRecords) {
                Optional<?> value = Optional.ofNullable(record.value());
                buffer.add(record);
                log.info("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<--------Consumer is Listening-------------->>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
                if (value.isPresent()) {

                    KafkaMessageEmailPolling message = (KafkaMessageEmailPolling)value.get();
                    log.info("---->"+message.getId()+"---->"+message.getSendTime()+"---->"+message.getEmailWorkItemConfig());
                    log.info("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<----------------->>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
                    workItemService.createWorkItem(message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Please help me know what I'm missing out and what are the Suggested changes here because as soon as I start Sending Notification about Downloaded Emails with Kafka My Application will stop working within an Hour or Two as total Thread Count Reaches to around 16K

Comment: There is something strange going on; with that configuration there should only be one producer created, shared by all. You should not be getting multiple produers.